# Downloading a file to the file system in WinJS

Tags: javascript, winjs

We are developing an app that is to download files from HTTP URLs, the extensions/file types of which we will not know until runtime.  We've been following [this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh868282.aspx) as a starting point, but since we aren't dealing with images, it hasn't helped us.

The issue is that the code in the tutorial will get you a [Blob](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh772298.aspx) object and I can't find any code that will allow us to either:

1. Convert the Blob to a byte array.
2. Save the Blob straight to the file system.

The ultimate goal is to seamlessly save the file at the given URL to the file system and launch it with the default application, or to just launch it from the URL directly (without the save prompt you get if you just call `Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri);`).

Any insight anyone might have is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding downloading content into byte array:
Using [WinJS.xhr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br229787.aspx) with the responseType option as 'arraybuffer' will return the contents in [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ArrayBuffer?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FJavaScript%2FTyped_arrays%2FArrayBuffer). A [javascript typed array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Typed_arrays) can be instantiated from the ArrayBuffer for example [UInt8Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Uint8Array?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FJavaScript%2FTyped_arrays%2FUint8Array). This way contents can be read into byte array. code should look something like this:

```
// todo add other options reqd
var options = { url: url, responseType: 'arraybuffer' }; 
WinJS.xhr(options).then(function onxhr(ab)
{
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(ab, 0, ab.byteLength);
}, function onerror()
{
    // handle error
});
```

Once you take care of permissions to save the file to file system either by user explicitly picking the save file location using [SaveFilePicker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj150595.aspx) or pick folder using [folder picker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) - file can be saved on local file system. Also, file can be saved to [app data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.aspx) folder.

AFAIK, html/js/css files from local file system or the app data cannot be loaded for security reasons. Although DOM can be manipulated under constraints, to add content. I am not sure of your application requirements. You might need to consider alternatives instead of launching downloaded html files.

Comment: Thanks @Sushil.  Exactly what we were looking for.  Everything works perfectly now.  We save the file to app data and launch it with no issues.

Comment: is the file html or image? as per documentation - image can work but not html.

Comment: It is normally an image of some kind.  But might also be a PDF or an office file.  HTML does not usually happen but we will see what happens with it.  Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: It shouldn't use "ab" directly but ab.response instead